# GFileMonitor - g_signal_handler_block "changed" signal doesn't block handler?

Tags: c, callback, gtk, gio

All,

This may take a moment to set up. I have a small editor project I've worked on the past several months[1]. I originally wanted to implement an `inotify` watch on the current editor file to protect against modification by a foreing process. I created a custom signal, and routines to `add`, `remove`, and `monitor` (with `pselect`) the watch and routines to `block` and `unblock` emission of the custom signal to allow for normal `save/save as` without triggering the callback. The problem I had was how to add the `monitor` to the `gtk_event_loop` so that a check was performed on each iteration of the loop. I settled on using `g_idle_add` and went to the **gtk-app-devel** list to determine if the approach was reasonable or if there was a better way. The concensus was to use GIO/`GFileMonitor` instead of working with `inotify` directly.

Fast forward to the current problem. I rewrote the implementation to use `GFileMonitor/g_file_monitor_file` and rewrote the `block` and `unblock` routines to block handling of the `"changed"` signal to allow a normal `save/save as` without firing the callback. The problem is when I `block` the instance and handler_id for the callback before saving the file, the callback still fires. When using the `inotify` implementation with a custom signal, blocking the emission of the signal worked great. I have posted this back to the **gtk-app-devel** list, but have received nothing in return -- that's why I'm asking here. Why does `g_signal_handler_block` with the GIO/`GFileMonitor` not block handling to the `"changed"` signal callback? (more importantly, how do I fix it)

**note:** (MCVE - complete test code is at https://github.com/drankinatty/gtktest). To build with GtkSourceView2, simply type `make with=-DWGTKSOURCEVIEW2`, it will build as `bin/gtkwrite`, otherwise to build without, simply type `make` and it will build as `bin/gtkedit`.

The logic of the relevant code is as follows (`app` is an instance of the `struct` holding relevant editor variables/info and settings) The GIO/GFileMonitor implementation is in `gtk_filemon.[ch]` and the wrapper around the save function is in `gtk_filebuf.c`:

```
typedef struct {
    ...
    gchar           *filename;
    GFileMonitor    *filemon;
    gulong          mfp_handler;
    ...
} kwinst;

kwinst *app = g_slice_new (kwinst);
```

I set the watch with:

```
GFile *gfile = g_file_new_for_path (app->filename);
...

/* create monitor for app->filename */
app->filemon = g_file_monitor_file (gfile,
                        G_FILE_MONITOR_NONE,
                        cancellable, &err);
...

/* connect changed signal to monitored file saving ID */
app->mfp_handler = g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT(app->filemon), "changed",
                        G_CALLBACK (file_monitor_on_changed), data);
```

Both the instance (`app->filemon`) and handler_id (`app->mfp_handler`) are saved. (`mfp` is just short for **modified by foreign process**) In order to prevent handling of changes during normal save/save as operations, I created block and unblock functions to prevent the changes to the file from firing the callback, e.g. show below with debug g_print calls:

```
void file_monitor_block_changed (gpointer data)
{
    kwinst *app = (kwinst *)data;

    if (!app->filemon || !app->mfp_handler) return;

    g_print ("blocking changed (%lu)\n", app->mfp_handler);

    g_signal_handler_block (app->filemon, app->mfp_handler);
}

void file_monitor_unblock_changed (gpointer data)
{
    kwinst *app = (kwinst *)data;

    if (!app->filemon || !app->mfp_handler) return;

    g_print ("unblocking changed (%lu)\n", app->mfp_handler);

    g_signal_handler_unblock (app->filemon, app->mfp_handler);
}
```

To implement the `block/unblock`, I wrap the file 'save/save as' function with the `block`, then save[2], then `unblock`, but the callback is still firing on normal saves. e.g. the relevant part of the save function I have is:

```
if (app->mfp_handler)                   /* current file monitor on file */
    file_monitor_block_changed (app);   /* block "changed" signal */

g_print ("  buffer_write_file (app, filename)\n");
buffer_write_file (app, filename);      /* write to file app->filename */

if (filename)
    file_monitor_add (app);             /* setup monitoring on new name */
else if (app->mfp_handler)
    file_monitor_unblock_changed (app); /* unblock "changed" signal */
```

With the debug `g_print` statements above, issuing `save` results in the following output:

```
$ ./bin/gtkwrite
blocking changed (669)
  buffer_write_file (app, filename)
unblocking changed (669)
Monitor Event: File = /home/david/tmp/foo.txt.UY9IXY
G_FILE_MONITOR_EVENT_DELETED
Monitor Event: File = /home/david/tmp/foo.txt
G_FILE_MONITOR_EVENT_CREATED
Monitor Event: File = /home/david/tmp/foo.txt
G_FILE_MONITOR_EVENT_CHANGES_DONE_HINT
Monitor Event: File = /home/david/tmp/foo.txt
G_FILE_MONITOR_EVENT_ATTRIBUTE_CHANGED
```

It makes no difference whether I include the `block/unblock`, the firing of the callback is unchanged. I suspect that the problem lies in the fact that the `"changed"` signal and it handling are implemented through `GIO` rather than `GTK` (as the custom signal for the `inotify` implementation was) and there being some difference in the abiliby to block handling of the `"changed"` signal using `g_signal_handler_block` -- though I cannot find a distinction in the documentation. The documentation states:

> ```
> To get informed about changes to the file or directory you are monitoring, 
> connect to the “changed” signal. The signal will be emitted in the thread-default 
> main context of the thread that the monitor was created in (though if the global 
> default main context is blocked, this may cause notifications to be blocked 
> even if the thread-default context is still running).
> ```

https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GFile.html#g-file-monitor-file

The application itself makes no use of any explicit threading and does not `fork` any part of the save. So I'm at a loss as to why the `block/unblock` does not prevent handling of the `"changed"` signal. The save is completely wrapped in the `block/unblock`, unless the `g_file_set_contents` call is asyncronous, there shouldn't be any timing issues I can see.

Why would calls to `g_signal_handler_block/g_signal_handler_unblock` fail to prevent handling of the `"changed"` signal emitted on changes to the current file? I can `g_signal_handler_disconnect` and nothing fires, but I shouldn't have to `disconnect` to temporarily block handling. What am I missing?

For completeness the `file_monitor_on_changed` function is included below along with the footnotes:

```
void file_monitor_on_changed (GFileMonitor *mon, 
                                GFile *file, GFile *other,
                                GFileMonitorEvent evtype,
                                gpointer data)
{
    kwinst *app = (kwinst *)data;

    g_print ("Monitor Event: File = %s\n", g_file_get_parse_name (file));

    switch (evtype)
    {
        case G_FILE_MONITOR_EVENT_CHANGED:
            /* prompt or emit custom signal modified by foreign process */
            g_print ("G_FILE_MONITOR_EVENT_CHANGED\n");
            break;
        case G_FILE_MONITOR_EVENT_CHANGES_DONE_HINT:
            g_print ("G_FILE_MONITOR_EVENT_CHANGES_DONE_HINT\n");
            break;
        case G_FILE_MONITOR_EVENT_DELETED:
            /* avoid firing on normal '.tmp' file delete */
            if (g_strcmp0 (g_file_get_parse_name (file), app->filename)) {
                g_print ("  ignoring 'tmp' file delete.\n");
                break;
            }
            /* prompt or emit custom signal modified by foreign process */
            g_print ("G_FILE_MONITOR_EVENT_DELETED\n");
            /* prompt save file */
            break;
        case G_FILE_MONITOR_EVENT_CREATED:
            g_print ("G_FILE_MONITOR_EVENT_CREATED\n");
            break;
        case G_FILE_MONITOR_EVENT_ATTRIBUTE_CHANGED:
            g_print ("G_FILE_MONITOR_EVENT_ATTRIBUTE_CHANGED\n");
            break;
        case G_FILE_MONITOR_EVENT_PRE_UNMOUNT:
            g_print ("G_FILE_MONITOR_EVENT_PRE_UNMOUNT\n");
            break;
        case G_FILE_MONITOR_EVENT_UNMOUNTED:
            g_print ("G_FILE_MONITOR_EVENT_UNMOUNTED\n");
            break;
        case G_FILE_MONITOR_EVENT_MOVED:
            g_print ("G_FILE_MONITOR_EVENT_MOVED\n");
            /* prompt save file */
            break;
        case G_FILE_MONITOR_EVENT_RENAMED:
            /* prompt save file */
            g_print ("G_FILE_MONITOR_EVENT_RENAMED\n");
            break;
        case G_FILE_MONITOR_EVENT_MOVED_IN:
            g_print ("G_FILE_MONITOR_EVENT_MOVED_IN\n");
            break;
        case G_FILE_MONITOR_EVENT_MOVED_OUT:
            g_print ("G_FILE_MONITOR_EVENT_MOVED_OUT\n");
            break;
        default:
            g_print ("unknown EVENT on changed signal.\n");
    }

    if (mon || other) {}
}
```

---

**Using g_signal_handler_block works fine in other cases**

As a point brought up in the comments, I can confirm I can easily `block`, `unblock` other signal handlers without issues. Specifically, when working with the `inotify` implementation, I created the following custom signal:

```
/* create signal to monitor file modified by foreign process */
app->SIG_MODFP = g_signal_new ("modified-foreign",
                                GTK_TYPE_TEXT_BUFFER,
                                GTK_RUN_ACTION,
                                0,
                                NULL,
                                NULL,
                                NULL,
                                G_TYPE_NONE,
                                1,
                                G_TYPE_POINTER);
```

Then connecting the signal to a handler and saving the handler_id as follows:

```
/* custom signals */
app->mfp_handler2 = g_signal_connect (GTK_TEXT_BUFFER(app->buffer), 
                  "modified-foreign",
                  G_CALLBACK (on_modified_foreign), app);
```

The `on_modified_foreign` callback is a simple test callback for purposes of testing the block/unblock:

```
void on_modified_foreign (GtkTextBuffer *buffer,
                        kwinst *app)
{
    dlg_info ("File has changed on disk, reload?", "Modified by Foreign Process");

    if (buffer || app) {}
}
```

Above `dlg_info` is just a wrapper to `gtk_message_dialog_new` to pop up a dialog when the `"modified-foreign"` signal is emitted.

Then implementing a simple test where one menuitem causes the signal to be emitted, e.g.:

```
void menu_status_bigredbtn_activate (GtkMenuItem *menuitem, kwinst *app)
{
    g_signal_emit_by_name (G_OBJECT(app->buffer), "modified-foreign::", app);
}
```

And, finally blocking/unblocking works just fine:

```
void menu_status_block_activate (GtkMenuItem *menuitem, kwinst *app)
{
    if (!app->mfp_handler2) return;
    GtkTextBuffer *buffer = GTK_TEXT_BUFFER(app->buffer);
    g_signal_handler_block (buffer, app->mfp_handler2);
}

void menu_status_unblock_activate (GtkMenuItem *menuitem, kwinst *app)
{
    if (!app->mfp_handler2) return;
    GtkTextBuffer *buffer = GTK_TEXT_BUFFER(app->buffer);
    g_signal_handler_unblock (buffer, app->mfp_handler2);
}
```

It all works fine. Select the `bigredbtn` menu item, the signal is emitted and up pops the dialog. Then selecting the `block` menu item and then again trying the `bigredbtn` -- nothing happens, no dialog, no nothing. Then selecting the `unblock` menu item and again selecting the `bigredbtn`, the dialog again pops up on each selection. (and the signals emitted while the handler was blocked were not queued and do not invoke the handler once it is unblocked)

So that is where I'm stuck. A large part of the problem is without picking though the GIO source line-by-line it, to a large extent, is a big black box. All works fine on the GTK side, but when doing the same thing involving a GIO function, the results seem not to work as expected.

Thanks for any other insight you may have on this issue.

***footnote 1:*** https://github.com/drankinatty/gtkwrite

***footnote 2:*** `buffer_write_file` calls `g_file_set_contents` to write to disk.

Comment: I have not verified this, but *it seems to me* that the "block" in [`g_signal_handler_block()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Signals.html#g-signal-handler-block) has the same semantics as a POSIX signal block: that is, that the delivery is only postponed until unblocked. (It should not be difficult to verify that this is actually what is happening, but one would need to delve into the GTK sources to verify this is intended. Or ask on the devel mailing list, perhaps.)

Comment: Well, that is what is entirely unclear, it works for some, not for others? Quoting `"Blocks a handler of an instance so it will not be called during any signal emissions unless it is unblocked again. Thus "blocking" a signal handler means to temporarily deactive it"`. So your analogy is probably correct, but when I block the emission on other signals, it works fine. So I know I'm missing something. It may very well be in the semantics of whether the **signal** is blocked or the **handler** is blocked. With GIO, its the handler, with GTK it's the signal -- you may have solved it `:)`

Comment: Uh, no, that's not it either. I've confirmed that there wasn't a distinction on the *emit/handle* issue. I can clearly block handlers in GTK without problems, in the GIO context, I'm having issues.

Comment: Right; I wonder whether GFileMonitor considers changes as *events* or *states*... Anyway, I personally would probably simplify the situation by adding custom state to the object representing the file -- `saved_size`, `saved_modified_time`, `actual_size`, `actual_modified_time`, `being_saved`, `saved_success` -- and not block the change signal at all, rather use the change signal to determine if the desired changes "took hold". This would make it more likely an external modification around the same time as save is correctly noted.

Comment: Yes, that is the other option. I can not `block/unblock` at all and just handle the changes by testing within the `file_monitor_on_changed()` function. The external modifications really only invoke the `CHANGED` and `DELETED` cases (a move is a delete/create). I sure liked the elegance of the block/unblock, but if it boils down to either *analyze the entire black box of GIO* **or** *implement test and forget the block/unblock*, option (2) is the winner! I uploaded the complete test code to [https://github.com/drankinatty/gtktest](https://github.com/drankinatty/gtktest)

Comment: Agreed. (The case for almost-simultaneous saves is real for me: sometimes I have a source file open in an editor (typically gedit), but forget and edit the same file in nano (typically to fix a simple typo); sometimes I remember and switch and save within less than a second. Instead of monitoring for *changes*, I want my editor to try and track whether the file is in the state I want it to be, with the option of discarding changes and reloading the file from storage if changes occur. `diff -u` functionality between file and memory would be quite useful in such conflicting situations, though.)

Comment: That is exactly the case I'm trying to protect against -- that and when I have a couple of test dirs set up concurrently and I do something dumb like copy a file to the wrong one.... (happens `:)`

Comment: Your debug output seems to clearly show that you do not get any signals while the handler is blocked: you get them after g_file_set_contents() call has returned. Right? Possibly the file system / inotify just works that way. You cannot ever be 100% sure the changes were yours and not some other app anyway: if you want to be sure to not lose data you need to handle the change signal even in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've played with it long enough, and I've found a solution. The key seems to be, for whatever reason in the grand scheme of GIO, to call the `block` and `unblock` from within the same source that the signals were originally connected in. For example, adding block/unblock functions within the `gtk_filemon.c` source and then calling from anywhere (as done from a test menu item above) works fine, e.g.:

```
void file_monitor_block_changed (gpointer data)
{
    kwinst *app = (kwinst *)data;

    if (!app->filemon || !app->mfp_handler) return;

    g_signal_handler_block (app->filemon, app->mfp_handler);
}

void file_monitor_unblock_changed (gpointer data)
{
    kwinst *app = (kwinst *)data;

    if (!app->filemon || !app->mfp_handler) return;

    g_signal_handler_unblock (app->filemon, app->mfp_handler);
}
```

This allows the calls from the above two functions in `menu_status_block_activate` and `menu_status_unblock_activate` to work as intended and successfully block handling of the `"changed"` signal while blocked, and resume when unblocked. Why it cannot be done by direct call to `g_signal_handler_block` and `g_signal_handler_unblock` using the *instance* and *handler_id* will just have to remain a documentation mystery for the time being.

**note:** I'll leave the github.com gtktest code up until mid-April if anyone wants to play with it, thereafter the working code will exist at https://github.com/drankinatty/gtkwrite.